# Open Server Как настроить кодировку?

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8, openserver

Видела аналогичную тему, но ответ не поняла. В каком именно файле нужно поменять на utf-8?

Установила Open Server, и на страницах, запущенных с его помощью отображаются исключительно кракозябры. Впрочем, страница приветствия - вполне читаемая. А мое творчество - нет

Пишу код в sublime text (установленном в систему, а не из папки `OpenServer\progs\_Office` - там я тоже его обнаружила, к удивлению своему).

Сохраняю файл с нужным расширением в `OpenServer\domains\test.ru\`

И при просмотре этого файла (.html или .php) в браузере - проблемы с кодировкой.

В OS - настройки - кодировки поставлена utf-8

Как исправить, подскажите!

P.S. Был вариант, что это Sublime Text меня подводит. Но в его настройках нашла строку: `"default_encoding": "UTF-8"`,  (в `Preferences.sublime-settings - Default`).

Значит, все-таки проблема в OpenServer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Привет. Нужно на все 100% убедиться с тем, что у вас документ в правильной кодировке.
В `Sublime Text 3` нужной зайти в `preferences -> settings`
Там будет файл в JSON формате, в настройки нужно добавить следующее:

```
"ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
"show_encoding": true,
```

первым параметром мы игнорируем Vintage mod в ST
а вторым выводим кодировку документа в правом нижнем углу.
Теперь открываем ваши файлы (там где кракозябры)
Если кодировка UTF-8, то все ок. если нет то `file -> save with encoding -> UTF-8`
Далее нужно в начало всех `<head></head>` добавить

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

И оно уже должно нормально работать)
Так как `Open Server` по умолчанию работает на `UTF-8`
Если не заработало, то будем копать дальше)

Мой файл настроек:

```js
{
 "bold_folder_labels": true,//Выделить жирным шрифтом имена папок в боковом меню.
 "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",//Тема оформления
 "draw_white_space": "all",//Показ символов пробелов и табуляций
 "fallback_encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)",//если ST не смог определить кодировку документа, то он его откроет в кодировке Cyrillic (Windows 1251)
 "font_size": 14,//Размер шрифта
 "highlight_line": true,//Подсветка ткущей линии (линии на которой каретка)
 "highlight_modified_tabs": true,//подсвечивает несохраненные вкладки документов
 "ignored_packages":
 [
  "Vintage"
 ],//игнорируем Vintage mod
 "indent_guide_options":
 [
  "draw_normal",
  "draw_active"
 ],//Подсвечиваем столбики между символами табуляции, столбец блока в котором каретка
 "show_encoding": true,//показ кодировки в правом нижнем углу
 "word_wrap": true//перенос длинных строк
}
```

только перед сохранением

Comment: Спасибо!! Файл нашла, Строку ,"ignored_packages":["Vintage"] тоже нашла - она последняя.              Но добавить "show_encoding": true, не могу. Не добавляется ни единого символа.          Может быть файл каким-то образом защищен от редактрования?

Comment: Пробую отредактировать в правой части программы. Вношу вместо {"font_size": 13}, которое там указано,      ,"show_encoding": true,

Comment: И получаю системное сообщение: "Error trying to parse settings:.Unexpected trailing characters in packages\user\Preferences.sublime-settings: 1:16"

Comment: @Наталья, судя по всему у вас в ST неправильные настройки кодировки... сохраните файл настроек таким образом: "file -> save with encoding -> UTF-8"

Comment: @Наталья, очень важно выбрать обычный UTF-8, а не UTF-8 with BOM. так как UTF-8 with BOM с дополнительными BOM символами...

Comment: Спасибо, чуть позже попробую и отпишусь о результатах

Comment: @Наталья, я в ответ добавил содержимое своего файла пользовательских настроек, можете им воспользоваться.

Comment: Спасибо, но я все равно не могу изменить содержание этого файла. В левой части окна, где, собственно, все настройки записаны, ничего не удается отредактировать. А из правой в левую ничего не переносится / не сохраняется

Comment: @Наталья, может вам через TeamViewer помочь? skype - php_array

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57930/discussion-between--and-).

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте рядом с файлом index.php файл .htaccess обязательно с точкой в начале и пропишите в самом файле `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`